# ASP.NET 6 Core Web API - strange POST result when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am experiencing strange behaviour when posting to an ASP.NET 6 Core Web API. I simplified the test to its minimal version with a simple `Get` and a simple `Post` controller methods.

In my development environment, Postman returns the correct data with both `get` and `post` requests to the API.

But when the API is deployed to Azure and I send a `POST` request, Postman returns the `GET` result instead of the `POST` result.

Looking at Postman log console, I can see the `POST` request is immediately followed by a `GET` request, which is not the case under development with IIS Express.

Here is my test controller, published at https://api2.matiasmasso.es/test

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost()]
        public IActionResult Post()
        {
            IActionResult retval = Ok("Success on Post!");
            return retval;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            IActionResult retval = Ok("Success on Get!");
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I hit your URL with Postman I get "Success on Post!"

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder, there must be something wrong in my Postman configuration. I created a new request from scratch and got the right result.

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? Feel free to share your concern on this.

Comment: Yes, the problem was on my Postman app, thanks

Comment: Glad to know that your problem has been resolved.